# MicroPython на ESP 32

Tags: micropython

Пытаюсь установить MicroPython на ESP 32. Сие манипуляции делаю под windows 7 параметры ПС на скрине [image: Параметры ПК]. Делаю всё как сказано в документации на сайте MicroPython http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/tutorial/intro.html#esp32-intro при попытке отформатировать плату пишет: ""esptool.py" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом." [image: скрин ошибки]

Так же не понятно почему плата не отображается на порте [image: скрин диспетчера устройств]. Предположил что дело в драйверах и установил их от сюда https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers в результате ни каких изменений.
[image: Фото платы]
[image: фото платы]

Помогите разобраться с этой проблемой. ))))

Comment: Попробуйте `python -m esptool` (и дальше остальные ключи командной строки)

Comment: `Так же не понятно почему плата не отображается на порте` - плата не обязана как-то по особенному отображаться в устройствах. Если при ее подключении к компьютеру появляется COM-порт - этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: "плата не обязана как-то по особенному отображаться в устройствах. Если при ее подключении к компьютеру появляется COM-порт - этого должно быть достаточно." этот порт отображается и в том  случае когда плата не подключенаб грубо говоря включай не включай ни чего не меняется (((

Comment: Так, а плата какая? Если через USB подключаете, попробуйте в разные порты вставлять. Также качество кабеля может иметь значение: обычные зарядные кабели могут не подойти.

Comment: Плата ESP32 Devkit v1 (фото добавил к вопросу). А какие кабели лучше использовать?

Comment: Вообще насколько я помню, пишут что нужны кабели с низким сопротивлением. Я использую такой https://amperka.ru/product/usb-cable-micro для Arduino, ESP8266, ESP32, с ним никаких проблем не наблюдается. Но возможно у вас все-таки проблема с драйверами.

Comment: Ок. понял. А где ещё можно драйвера найти? а то я только на оном сайте их нашёл.

Comment: Спасибо проблема решилась заменой кабеля))